# Physics of cutting

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm trying to do some research on how the use of a wedge (blade) relates to the shear stress and applied force to cut an object.

I have an understanding of the shear modulus, and of the mecahnics of a wedge, but how do the two combine?

Why is it easier to cut with a sharp knife vs a dull knife?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134119/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38021/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This has been a topic of interest in the mechanical engineering field for many years. If you post this question on the engineering SE you might get better responses.